# Re Positioning html text

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to re positioning the `<em>` tag in label field using jQuery

```
From: <label><em>*</em> Name</label>
  To: <label>Name <em>*</em></label>
```

Also check the label contain `<em>` tag or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do you want the new position to be?

Comment: Also need to check the if label contain <em> tag or not.

Comment: This does not seem to be about positioning but about changing the DOM. Insufficient information is given about the nature of the intended manipulation. Besides, there is no attempt at solving the problem, just an open request to others to do some programming work (without sufficient specifications).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle> http://jsfiddle.net/74gP2/

```
$('label em').remove();
$('label').append('<em>*</em>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var contents = $('label').contents();
var len = contents.length;
$('label').prepend(contents[len-1]);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9BPLh/)